# Integral with a hyperbolic function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I'm struggling with the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \operatorname{sech}^4 (a x+b) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^2\right)=1-3b^2+4a^6$$

I believe I'm supposed to be solving it by power expanding the hyperbolic function (other methods are appreciated too). So I've first recast this integral as:

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d m}{a \sqrt{2 \pi}} \operatorname{sech}^4 m \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 a^2}(m-b)^2\right)$$

And then Taylor expanded the hyperbolic up to 2nd order:

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d m}{a \sqrt{2 \pi}}\left(1-2 m^2\right) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 a^2}(m-b)^2\right)$$

For simplicity used $k = m-b$ and:

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d k}{a \sqrt{2 \pi}}\left(1-2(k+b)^2\right) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 a^2} k^2\right)$$

Evaluating it I got:

$$=1-2 b^2-2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d k}{a \sqrt{2 \pi}} k^2 \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 a^2} k^2\right)$$

Which is:

$$=1-2 b^2-2 a^2$$

But I'm supposed to be getting:

$$=1-3b^2+4a^6$$

I'm so close but I just can't see where my mistake is. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you can truncate the $sech^4(x)$ Taylor series at quadratic order?

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Just take $a=0$, and you get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \operatorname{sech}^4 (b) \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^2\right)=\operatorname{sech}^4 (b)\neq1-3b^2$$

Comment: Yes the quadratic order for small a and b should be adequate. The result is correct if you Taylor expand first, and then set $a=0$ which is what I ask in the problem. You're however free to solve it however to your liking without consulting to the result

Comment: As far as I can see the LHS $\to 0$ as $a \to \infty$ while the RHS $\to \infty$.

Comment: I checked numerically, and these solutions aren't correct. Where did you get the solution from?

Comment: It is from this paper: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/11/5/028 (eqn. 22). What did you get numerically?

Answer (score 1):

After the first substitution, we have (as you wrote it)

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \text{sech}^4(m) e^{-\frac{(m-b)^2}{2 a^2}}\,dm$$

By Taylor
$$ \text{sech}^4(m)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,m^{2n}$$ where the first coefficients are

$$\left\{1,-2,\frac{7}{3},-\frac{94}{45},\frac{502}{315},-\frac{221
   2}{2025},\frac{324419}{467775},-\frac{17698598}{42567525},\frac{21746206}{91216125}\right\}$$

Just for your curiosity

$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} m^{2n}\,e^{-\frac{(m-b)^2}{2 a^2}}\,dm$$
$$I_n=2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} a^{2 n+1} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(-n;\frac{1}{2};-\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}\right)$$ where appears Kummer's hypergeometric function.

Anyhow, computing and summing the first terms, we have

$$I=\color{red}{(1-2a^2-2b^2)}+14 a^2 b^2+7a^4+\frac{7}{3} b^4+\cdots$$ which is your result for a first approximation when $(a,b)$ are small.

Using $a=b=\frac 1{10}$ your formula gives for the integral $\frac{24}{25}=0.96$ while numerical integration leads to $0.962186$. Using
what I wrote would give $\frac{2887}{3000}=0.962333$ which is a marginal improvement.